# How can I point this string to the structure?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


    typedef struct{
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    int id; 
    char gender[10]; 
    int monthOfBirth; 
    int dayOfBirth; 
    int yearOfBirth; 
    } HealthProfile;


void setName(HealthProfile *HP) {
    char firstName;
    char lastName; 
    printf("Enter your first and last name: ");
    scanf("%s" "%s", &firstName, &lastName);
    HP->firstName = firstName;
    HP->lastName = lastName; 
}

void setID(HealthProfile *HP) {
    int id; 
    printf("Enter ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &id);
    HP->id = id;
}

void setGender(HealthProfile *HP) {
    char gender;
    // HealthProfile hp;
   // strcpy(hp.gender, &gender); 
    printf("Enter your gender: ");
    scanf("%s", &gender);

    HP->gender = gender;

}
void setBD(HealthProfile *HP) {
    int monthOfBirth;
    int dayOfBirth;
    int yearOfBirth; 
    printf("Enter your month of birth, day of birth and year of birth: ");
    scanf("%d" "%d" "%d", &monthOfBirth, &dayOfBirth, &yearOfBirth);
    HP->monthOfBirth = monthOfBirth;
    HP->dayOfBirth = dayOfBirth;
    HP->yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth; 
}

int main(){
    // pointer declared to HealthProfile structure 
    HealthProfile *HP;
    // pointer initialized using malloc 
    HP = (HealthProfile*) malloc(sizeof(HealthProfile));

// Calls various functions

    setID(HP); 
    setGender(HP);
    setName(HP);
    setBD(HP);

    // Creates your profile
    printf("Creating your Health Profile! \n");
    printf("Profile created for: %s\n", HP->firstName);
    printf("Lastname: %s\n", HP->lastName);
    // prints ID 
    printf("ID: %d\n", HP->id);
    printf("Gender: %s\n", HP->gender);
    printf("Month of birth: %d\n", HP->monthOfBirth); 
    printf("day of birth: %d\n", HP->dayOfBirth);
    printf("year of birth: %d\n", HP->yearOfBirth);
}
```

What I am trying to do is assign HP to  a string but I get this error.

```
array type 'char [10]' is not assignable
    HP->gender = gender;
```

(same error with first and last name of course) So I searched online and found out that char can't be assigned and strcpy should be used instead. As you can see by my failed attempt in the gender function.

Can someone help me fix my errors? Thanks

Comment: `char gender;` - gender is not an array. It is only an object of type `char`. Edit it to `char gender[7]`.

Comment: Same is applicable here `HP->firstName = firstName;`. firstly you wanted `firstName` to be of _char array_ type not just a char type, then you can't assign directly one array with another. Try `strncpy(HP->firstName, firstName, MAX_LENGTH);`

Comment: You really don't want fixed-length buffers in structs. Consider using `char*` and dynamic allocation if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've discovered, you can't assign directly to an array.  For strings in particular, you would need to use `strcpy` to copy a string from one array to another.

Additionally, `gender` is a single character, not an array.  So passing `&gender` to `scanf` will cause the function to treat it as a pointer to a sequence of characters instead of a pointer to just one, resulting in the function writing past the memory bounds of the variable.

You can fix this by making `gender` an array of the proper size:

```
void setGender(HealthProfile *HP) {
    char gender[10];
    printf("Enter your gender: ");
    scanf("%s", gender);
    strcpy(HP->gender, gender);
}
```

Or you could skip the temp variable entirely and write directly to the field in the struct:

```
void setGender(HealthProfile *HP) {
    printf("Enter your gender: ");
    scanf("%s", HP->gender);
}
```

And do the same for reading `firstname` and `lastname`.

Comment: when using `scanf` into fixed buffers your should ALWAYS specify a length limit:  `scanf("%9s", gender);` to avoid overflowing the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`char gender;` - `gender` is not an array. It is only one object of type `char`.

Thus, `HP->gender = gender;` does not work because `gender` does not decay to a pointer to `char` like an array would do.

Edit it to `char gender[10]`.

Answer (score 0):

actually I think that you should not using Assignment for string and array .Instead you  should use strcpy and include string.h library.